# Poisson process: Calculate E[N(t)N(t+s)]

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, expected-value, markov-process

I'm trying to understand the solution to question 1 in this:
http://dept.stat.lsa.umich.edu/~ionides/620/hw/hw2sol.pdf

$E[(N(t))^2]$ + $E[N(t)]$ * $E[N(s)]$ = ($\lambda$$t$)$^2$ + $\lambda$$t$$\lambda$$s$ + $\lambda$$t$

Where does the very last $\lambda$$t$ come from? The first two components directly follow from the previous... Is there something around dependence I'm missing?

Comment: $N(t)$ and $N(s)$ are _dependent_ random variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: try to get it where you can use independent increments property (second to last line) and stationarity property (last line) of Poisson Processes.
\begin{align*}
E[N(t)N(t+s)] &= E[N(t)\{N(t+s) - N(t) + N(t) \}] \\
&= E[N(t)\{N(t+s) - N(t)\}  + N(t)N(t) ] \\
&= E[N(t)\{N(t+s) - N(t)\}]  + E[N(t)N(t) ] \\
&= E[N(t)]E[\{N(t+s) - N(t)\}] + \left(Var(N(t) + E[N(t)]^2 \right) \\
&= E[N(t)]E[N(s)] + \left(Var(N(t) + E[N(t)]^2 \right) .
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense - as in I can get from your last step to the solution because there is an extra variance term that yields the $\lambda$$t$ that I was missing.

However the solution makes the step from my initial question rightaway - am I missing the obvious shortcut here?

Comment: Also, is E[N(t)²] the same as E[N(t)]² (I wouldn't think so...?) or is that where the extra terms comes from?

Comment: $E[X^2] = V[X] + (E[X])^2$. You never plug in a second moment. You plug in means and variances. They are very different.

Comment: Here we go - that's our solution then! I should have known this really. Just getting back into it all... Thanks a lot!

Comment: no sweat @mike24 glad to help